# clean uiwebview cache in ios

Tags: ios, caching, uiviewcontroller

I am using uiwebview to show my web contents. Navigating to different url using RevealViewController. I am caching all the pages for the first time entry.

After visiting few pages when trying to goto rear view (reveal view controller menu screen), the app got stuck for some time on clicking of the menu button.

(Every time visiting and caching a page that will increase the memory size of the app)

Answer (score 0):

If the presentation of the menu is slow, it is probably because you are doing some heavy processsing inside the `initialiser` of the menu or the `viewDidLoad` function, or the menu button pressed function.

My suggestion is to move any of that processing to the viewDidAppear method of your menu controller instead, so that the UI is not blocked by any processing you do.  You could also use GCD to `disaptch_async` anything that is intensive.

If you give some code examples it will be easier to see exactly what the problem is, particularly the code that executes when the menu button is pressed.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
facing this problem after loading webview multiple times. and then clicking on menu button.